# What's the difference between setattr() and object.__setattr__()?

Tags: python, setattr

I know that you can't call `object.__setattr__` on objects not inherited from `object`, but is there anything else that is different between the two? I'm working in Python 2.6, if this matters.

Comment: `setattr` is something that you call on another object, `__setattr__()` is something that you implement on your own object.

Comment: `setattr(obj, attr, value)` just calls `obj.__setattr__(attr, value)`, at least for new-style classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reading this question again I misunderstood what @paper.cut was asking about: the difference between classic classes and new-style classes (not an issue in Python 3+).  I do not know the answer to that.

---

### Original Answer<sup>*</sup>

`setattr(instance, name, value)` is syntactic sugar for `instance.__setattr__(name, value)`<sup>**</sup>.

You would only need to call `object.__setattr__(...)` inside a class definition, and then only if directly subclassing `object` -- if you were subclassing something else, `Spam` for example, then you should either use `super()` to get the next item in the heirarchy, or call `Spam.__setattr__(...)` -- this way you don't risk missing behavior that super-classes have defined by skipping over them directly to `object`.

---

<sup>*</sup> applies to Python 3.0+ classes and 2.x new-style classes

---

<sup>**</sup>There are two instances where `setattr(x, ...)` and `x.__setattr__(...)` are not the same:

- `x` itself has a `__setattr__` in it's private dictionary (so `x.__dict__[__setattr__] = ...` (this is almost certainly an error)
- `x.__class__` has a `__getattribute__` method -- because `__getattribute__` intercepts *every* lookup, even when the method/attribute exists

**NB**
These two caveats apply to every syntactic sugar shortcut:

- `setattr`
- `getattr`
- `len`
- `bool`
- `hash`
- etc

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. The code is probably using `object.__setattr__` for the exact purpose of skipping the superclass's __setattr__.

Comment: _"setattr(instance, name, value) is syntactic sugar for instance.__setattr__(name, value)"_ - is it really? I vaguely remember that some types don't have `__getattr__` but getting attributes works for them regardless. Isn't it the same here?

Comment: For a subtle caveat, see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144186

Comment: @Maxpm:  Your question deals with `super`, which should only be used as documented.