# Python 2.7: What does object.__setattr__ do under the hood?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes, python-internals

In Python 2.7, I can declare a new-style class and set an attribute using `object.__setattr__`:

```
class A (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'foo', 'bar')

A().foo # 'bar'
```

However, this does not work in an old-style class:

```
class B:
    def __init__ (self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'foo', 'bar')

B().foo
```

> TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to instance object

I know that old-style classes do not support this behaviour, but I do not know why it doesn't work.

What is going on under the hood when I call `object.__setattr__` on a new-style class that cannot occur for old-style classes?

Please note that I am not using this code for anything, I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: `object` is the base for new-style classes, so no, you can't use `object.__setattr__` on instances that are not inheriting from that base.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand why that is - I am missing something here about how this works

Comment: *Please note that I am aware that there are only very special circumstances when one would use object.__setattr__ instead of setattr*. Do enlighten us, in what circumstances would you want to not use `setattr()` here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559170/604687). You can also find [examples of this usage in the pandas core](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f6f5ce5f9ce2afc3b6f55a3228b93024b121b88f/pandas/core/generic.py#L130).

Comment: Well, if you don't inherit from `object` that one case *doesn't apply*. The exception there being that an intermediary class in the MRO is being skipped.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ha, good point. Clearly this is somewhat contrived, but I didn't want people asking me in the comments why I was doing this as I'm not using it for anything - I'll re-word

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `object.__setattr__` method includes a specific check to make sure that `self` passed in is really a (subclass) of object (or another object that reuses the same C function directly). That test doesn't allow for anything else being passed in, including old-style instances.

The check is there to prevent `object.__setattr__` being used to modify *built-in types* (known as the *Carlo Verre* hack, after its discoverer.

Without the explicit check (or if you compiled Python to disable it), you could do this:

```
>>> object.__setattr__(str, 'lower', str.upper)
>>> "This is why we can't have nice things".lower()
"THIS IS WHY WE CAN'T HAVE NICE THINGS"
```

See the [`hackcheck()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.13/Objects/typeobject.c#L4683-L4701), and the [original Python-dev discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/034535.html).

That old-style instance objects don't pass the test is just a side-effect.

Note that the **only** reason you'd ever want to call `object.__setattr__` is if you have a base class that implements a `__setattr__` method you need to bypass.  For old-style instances, you could just use `self.__dict__[name] = value` instead.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. I did not see any reason *why*, technically, this call would fail. Now I understand.

Comment: Of course, you can still do `gc.get_referents(str.__dict__)[0]['lower'] = str.upper` to make `str.lower` uppercase things anyway, so it's still pretty easy to screw with built-in types if you really want to.

Comment: @user2357112: yup, there are other loopholes to exploit, and perhaps those too should be closed. Wanna bring that one to the dev list and see if it is worth closing?

Comment: @user2357112: actually, that one doesn't work for me, not in 2.7 at least. In 3.6 it leads to a segfault!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [Here's an Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/wpR1HB) you can compare against to see if you did something different from what I did.

Comment: @user2357112 I get segfaults 2.7 and 3.6 running that exact code in a python shell, but not in 2.7 when executing a script

Comment: Try it in a fresh interpreter. I think the `lower` lookup is hitting the method cache and trying to access the old `str.lower`, which has probably been deallocated. (This kind of thing is unsupported and dangerous, so it's not much of a surprise that crazy things go wrong.)

Comment: @user2357112: yup, it then works in a 2.7 interpreter session. 3.6 still segfaults (both in the REPL and as a script).

Comment: @user2357112: I'm sure this can be done using ctypes too, I just can't be bothered to write that all out.

Answer (score 1):

The type - not the old-style class, but the type - of all old-style instances is `types.InstanceType`. This type is written in C and implements its own `__setattr__`. Python will refuse to apply the `__setattr__` of one C type to instances of a C type with a different C-level `__setattr__`, as a safety measure to protect the consistency of C data structures.

Comment: Yet the C data structures are the same here; with old-style attributes there are no descriptors that can hook into `__set__` anyway, so setting an attribute is always a `__dict__[attrname] = attrvalue` operation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: They're actually not quite the same - for example, InstanceType doesn't provide the metadata `object.__setattr__` would need to locate the instance's `__dict__` in the first place.

Comment: Right, indeed, one has `in_dict`, the other a `tp_dictoffset` offset into the slots. Still, could have been handled in an abstraction internally.