# Why isn't setattr(super(), ...) equivalent to super().__setattr__(...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559315/497934):

> `setattr(instance, name, value)` is syntactic sugar for `instance.__setattr__(name, value)`

But:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        # OK.
        super().__setattr__("foo", 123)

        # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
        setattr(super(), "foo", 123)

c = C()
```

What gives? Shouldn't they both do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you linked to glosses over some important details. Long story short, `setattr` bypasses `super`'s magic, so it tries to set attributes on the `super()` proxy object itself instead of on `self`.

---

`setattr(a, b, c)` is not syntactic sugar for `a.__setattr__(b, c)`. `setattr` and regular attribute assignment both look for a `__setattr__` method through a direct search of an object's type's [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (a carefully-ordered list of the class and all superclasses), bypassing both the instance dict and `__getattribute__`/`__getattr__` hooks.

In contrast, `a.__setattr__(b, c)` just performs a regular attribute lookup for `__setattr__`, so it goes through `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__`, and it checks the instance dict unless `__getattribute__` says not to.

---

`super` implements a custom `__getattribute__` method to do its attribute magic. `super().__setattr__` uses this hook, finding `C`'s superclass's `__setattr__` and binding `self`, resulting in a method object for setting attributes on `self`.

`setattr(super(), ...)` bypasses `__getattribute__`. It performs the direct MRO search mentioned previously, searching through `super`'s MRO, resulting in a method object for setting attributes on the *super instance itself*. The `super` instance doesn't have a `__dict__` to store arbitrary attribute data in, so trying to set a `foo` attribute fails with a `TypeError`.

Comment: So, the conceit of `super()` doesn't hold up under `setattr(super(), ...)` because `super()` doesn't actually have the `__mro__` it pretends to?  Is this limitation officially documented anywhere?  The [`super()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) have a note on it being "undefined for implicit lookups using statements or operators," but I don't think that this is an implicit lookup.

Comment: @Maxpm: This is just as implicit as the lookup involved in regular attribute access. Despite the very similar names, `setattr` is not an explicit `__setattr__` lookup.

Comment: As for the `super` docs, the `super` docs are really quite terrible. They don't even say enough to explain how ordinary usage of `super` works. That said, they do explain that `super` works by implementing `__getattribute__`, and `__getattribute__` isn't triggered for these kinds of operations.

Comment: @user2357112: Your answer doesn't explain the difference between `setattr(...)` and `instance.__setattr__(...)`.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I've added some more explanation. It's hard to find the right balance between not explaining enough and overexplaining too many distracting details. I could go on and on about the differences between regular attribute lookup, special method lookup, and `super.__getattribute__`, talk about `tp_setattro` and how the MRO search is usually optimized away, talk about the descriptor protocol, talk about how the descriptor protocol is also usually optimized away, etc.

Comment: @user2357112:  I updated my answer on the other question.  I'd appreciate your feedback.